# Duck Punch jQuery .on to wrap callback in try/catch

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm logging client exceptions in JavaScript. To get a stack trace, I need to wrap code in a try/catch.

Instead of wrapping every callback individually, I tried to 'duck punch' jQuery's `.on()` method.

For the most part it has worked, but for some reason it's busting my jQueryUI sortable.  If I comment out the following code, the sortable works fine. How can I properly intercept the `on` event and make sure I get the arguments and context right?

```
if(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.on){
  //keep a reference to the original `on`
  var _on = jQuery.fn.on;

  //replace `on` with my version
  jQuery.fn.on = function() {

    //start from the end, looking for the callback
    for(var i=arguments.length-1; i>=0; i--){

      //is this the function?
      if(typeof arguments[i] == 'function'){

        //keep a reference to the callback
        var func = arguments[i];

        //replace the callback
        arguments[i] = function(){
          try{
            //call the original callback
            func.apply(this, arguments);
          }catch(e){
            ...
          }
        };
        break;
      }
    }

    //call the original `on` with our new arguments
    return _on.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `window.onerror` event instead? That way you're not try/catching everything. The only obvious thing I see wrong here is that `this` gets accidentally reassigned, but I can't imagine a case in which that matters.

Comment: thanks @ClintTseng - `onerror` doesn't provide a stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.on){
    //keep a reference to the original `on`
    var _on = jQuery.fn.on;

    //replace `on` with my version
    jQuery.fn.on = function() {
        var self = this;
        //start from the end, looking for the callback
        for(var i=arguments.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            (function(idx){

                //is this the function?
                if(typeof arguments[idx] == 'function'){

                    //keep a reference to the callback
                    var func = arguments[idx];

                    //replace the callback
                    arguments[idx] = function(){
                        try{
                            //call the original callback
                            func.apply(self, arguments);
                        }catch(e){
                        }
                    };
                }
            })(i)
        }

        //call the original `on` with our new arguments
        return _on.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/efTL9/)

Comment: That did it. I guess my problem was `this` getting redefined.

Comment: Actually, it's your `func` getting reassigned, now that I'm looking more closely. Arun has also decided to preserve `idx` here, which is unnecessary but if your code changes could be in the future.